# Initializing an int variable as in between 2 values in Java

Tags: java, variables

I'm totally new to Java, and I'm facing a little problem. Sometimes I need to declare a numerical variable in between two values like `int x>=2 && x<=20;` but I can't find a way to do that.

For example I have this problem to solve:

> Given an integer, N, print its first 10 multiples. Each multiple N*i (where 1 <= i <= 10) should be printed on a new line in the form: N x i = result.
>
> Constraints
>
> 2 <= N <= 20

How can i solve that, and how can I initialize an int variable "in between two values" ?

Comment: `N` is given. You're probably meant to read in the value from the console.

Comment: Thanks guys, i got the answer that i want, thanks a lot for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to "initialize a variable between 2 values", as a variable can have only 1 value at a time.

You should give the different possible values to the variable one by one :

```
int i=1;
while(i<=10){
   System.out.println("N x " + i + " = " + (N*i));
   i++;
}
```

#### Final result

If you don't want to keep your `i` variable after you can use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i=1; i<= 10; i++){
   System.out.println("N x "+ i +" = " + (N*i));
}
```

You can do the same if you want to do this for all the specified values of N:

```
for(int N = 2; N <= 20; N++)
   for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
      System.out.println("N x "+ i +" = " + (N*i));
```

#### About variables with several values

In software programming, the very concept of a variable is a "placeholder to store a value". So by definition, a variable can hold only one value, and is doing so at any time.

When you see variables that seem to hold several values, they are actually holding 1 value, which itself is a container for several values.

Comment: Thanks, you've helped me a lot, that was right and easy!

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad I helped

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give an `int` variable a range as its value. However, it is possible to change the value of an `int` at runtime.

For the given problem, there are two approaches I might consider using.

**Taking a command line argument**

You can write your program to take a value given on the command line and assign it to your `int` variable. Assuming you are within your main method, command line arguments are kept in the `args` array and can be accessed like this...

`int value = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`

This will store the first argument given on the command line in the variable `value`, provided it is parseable as an integer. So if you run the program with the command `java Program 10`, then `value` will be assigned value 10.

**Asking the user for input**

Look up the `Scanner` class and use it to ask the user for a value in the range that you want.

Like this...

`Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int value = in.nextInt();`

Obviously if you want to make sure that the given values lie in your desired range this can also be checked at runtime pretty easily.

Comment: thanks for your effort, i appreciate your help a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't allow to specify range of variable like python's range(int,int) method . However you can use Range class from apache commons library.

For your problem, there is no need to declare variables value beforehand. Just initialize the variable with the lowest value ,perform some calculation and increment the variable in a loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
         int n = 2;
                 while(n<=20){
                     for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
                         System.out.println(n+"X"+i+"="+n*i);
                     }
                     n=n+1;
                 }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me :)